# UDTs in modules

Tags: content-management-system, udp-data-transfer, cmsmadesimple

I'm trying to call a UDT from within a module's content using CMS Made Simple v1.11.7. Is there a way to process content so that UDTs are executed? I'd like to process this module's content the same way as page content so user defined tags and global content blocks are available.

Answer (score 0):

The execution of the UDT in a module depends on the implementation of the module. In some cases, it execute the smarty inside the module content, and in some other cases, it does not execute the logic inside the detail. You cannot change this yourself unfortunately.

Some modules do both like MCFactory, where in the module template, you can use `{$ModuleName->detail}` to show the raw content of the field detail while if you use `{$ModuleName->getDetail()}`, it execute the smarty logic inside the detail field